# How to force text to move down instead of to the side when avoiding another element WITH CSS ONLY

Tags: html, css, formatting

If you have a look at [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THnh1.png), you can see that the comment's contents have positioned themselves somewhat undesirably because of the user avatar next to them. I'd like the text to stretch from side to side, what means that it should move down, instead of moving to the side, when there's another element in the way ([the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KLlj.png)).

Unfortunately, I'm unable to edit the HTML and I can only change the CSS. I have tried playing around with margins, padding and avatar dimensions, but these solutions only work for one view and break apart in another (PC -> mobile, etc.)

The HTML is structured followingly:

```html
<div class="comment-body">
  <div class="comment-info"></div>
    <div class="comment-author"></div> <!--contains username and avatar-->
    <div class="comment-date"></div>
  <div class="comment-content"></div>
</div>
```

If there was a way to force both divs to respect their individual rectangular bounds, it would fix my problem, but I wasn't able to find anything through googling.

Apologies if I forgot to include something, this is my first stackoverflow question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would recommend adding an example of the HTML with a photo and content as well as the CSS that you have tried.

Comment: Hello. I should have indeed posted a more detailed code breakdown right away, but I managed to solve my problem in the meantime. I left an answer below describing the solution, I hope it helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after trying everything possible with the text and with the avatar elements, I finally figured out that I could just use `overflow: auto` on the div containing both the avatar and the user information. This adjusted the div's boundaries and prevented the text from flowing into the free region right below the username and date (boundaries [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPIWB.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPCZo.png)).

The simplified HTML:

```html
<div class="comment-body">
  <div class="comment-info"></div>
    <div class="comment-author"></div> <!--contains username and avatar-->
    <div class="comment-date"></div>
  <div class="comment-content"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.comment-info {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say much without seeing the CSS, but have you tried floating the element?

Like `selector { float:left; }`

Comment: This reads more like a comment than an answer to me: One of the primary purposes of the question's comment section is to ask for clarification or more details from the asker.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you commented with an example of the clarification you were expecting.